# Use of verbatim quotes in reporting findings in qualitative research (semi-structured interviews)

Tags: quotation

In qualitative research (semi- structured interviews) do we have to use verbatim quotes in reporting the findings?

Answer (score 2):

There is no prescription.

However, it is always nice and useful to convey through your report the 'voices' of the interviewees through carefully selected quotes, i.e. the most significant, revealing or unique.

Hope that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that there is no prescription to use quotes however more than being nice, using quotes provides verification.

In qualitative research we speak of verification instead of validity. So using a rigorous process and describing it for the readers helps verify the findings of your work. Using "rich" quotation to give context and voice to the participants is one method, among others such as triangulation, member checking, or collaboration.